# finding matching or non matching values in r

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a medium sized data frame like the one I made up below, (with several columns though) where I want to find if any "id"s have different "letter"s
I imagine that there is a simple way to do this, maybe with tidyr?

```
df<-data.frame("id"=c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6), "letter"=c("f", "f", 
"r", "r", "k", "k", "k", "k", "r", "f", "r"))
```

EDIT: I am trying to find the "id"s that have more than one letter. i.e. in this df  id 3 and 6. I am less interested in which "letter"s (though it's not bad if they're shown), more in which "id"s

Comment: Please elaborate: Are you trying to just keep the unique letter values, or specifically look for non-{'f','k','r'} values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of your desired output, but you can check to see how many `letter`s correspond to each `id` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(n_letters = n_distinct(letter))

A tibble: 6 x 2
     id n_letters
  <dbl>     <int>
1     1         1
2     2         1
3     3         2
4     4         1
5     5         1
6     6         2
```

If you just want a vector of the `id`s with only 1 letter:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(n_letters = n_distinct(letter)) %>%
  filter(n_letters == 1) %>%
  pull(id)

[1] 1 2 4 5
```

Or if you want a df of the `id`s with more than 1 letter:

```
multiple_letter_ids <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(n_letters = n_distinct(letter)) %>%
  filter(n_letters > 1) %>%
  pull(id)

df %>% filter(id %in% multiple_letter_ids)

 id letter
1  3      r
2  3      k
3  3      k
4  6      f
5  6      r
```

Comment: Since I have a lot of what I am here calling "id"s is there anyway to get r to show just the "id"s where the "n_letter" is > 1?

Comment: Hi Mactilda.  I updated my posted and I think the last bit of code will produce what you are looking for?

Comment: Yey! Thank you. One of these days I will have learnt enough to figure these things out myself. :)

Comment: Just another question: If I wanted to know how many ids that have more than one letter, is it easier to make a new df and summarise or could it be done with the first step? I am sorry for the basic questions but I am learning...

Comment: It's okay, we are all still learning.  Are you looking for just a count of how many contain more than one letter?  `df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(n_letters = n_distinct(letter)) %>%
  filter(n_letters > 1) %>%
  nrow()`